# TabbedPaneUI paint selected tab

Tags: java, swing, custom-component

i would like to paint the selected tab in a different way than other tab, it works the first time but then the repaint doesn't work.

Here is the code i did inside paintTabBackground :

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    if (isSelected) {
        BufferedImage background = tabSelected;
        Insets insets = getTabInsets(tabPlacement, tabIndex);
        Rectangle tabBound = getTabBounds(tabPane, tabIndex);
        tileStretchPaint(g2d, tabBound, background, insets);
    } else {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        super.paintTabBackground(g2d, tabPlacement, tabIndex, x, y, w, h, isSelected);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the graphics

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

and don't dispose it

Comment: No, it won't repaint when i select a new tab, by casting it.